# How to technical write, "...is the first of its kind"

Tags: phrase-requests, technical

How can I write the following in technical terms

> "Hence, to the best our knowledge, the analysis provided in the
>   following sections for .... by an ABC-node is the first of its kind."

Comment: "First of its kind" is probably ok. You could also call it "original".

Comment: Because *technical writing* can mean a few things, it would help to clarify what context you mean by that. "The first of its kind," "novel use," and other phrasings may all be acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in:

"Hence, to the best our knowledge, the analysis provided in the following sections for .... by an ABC-node is a **novel** use."

**novel**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/novel)

> adj. Strikingly new, unusual, or different.